# GPU under utilization using tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

[image: TF Trace]

During training of my data, my GPU utilization is around 40%, and I clearly see that there is a datacopy operation that's using a lot of time, based on tensorflow profiler(see attached picture). I presume that "MEMCPYHtoD" option is copying the batch from CPU to GPU, and is blocking the GPU from being used. Is there anyway to prefetch data to GPU? or is there other problems that I am not seeing?

Here is the code for dataset:

```
X_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, data.train.X.shape)
y_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, data.train.y[label].shape)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({"X": X_placeholder, 
                                              "y": y_placeholder})
dataset = dataset.repeat(1000)
dataset = dataset.batch(1000)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
```

Comment: Related threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965098/how-does-one-move-data-to-multiple-gpu-towers-using-tensorflows-dataset-api
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610

Comment: Another related thread, queues tied to the GPU for pre-fetching look like they're slated for somewhere in 1.5: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5722

Comment: One more relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965098/how-does-one-move-data-to-multiple-gpu-towers-using-tensorflows-dataset-api/46966248#46966248

Answer (score 5):

**Prefetching to a single GPU**:

- Consider using a more flexible approach than `prefetch_to_device`, e.g. by explicitly copying to the GPU with `tf.data.experimental.copy_to_device(...)` and then prefetching. This allows to avoid the restriction that `prefetch_to_device` must be the last transformation in a pipeline, and allow to incorporate further tricks to optimize the `Dataset` pipeline performance (*e.g.* by overriding threadpool distribution).
- Try out the experimental `tf.contrib.data.AUTOTUNE` option for prefetching, which allows the `tf.data` runtime to automatically tune the prefetch buffer sizes based on your system and environment.

At the end, you might end up doing something like this:

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.copy_to_device("/gpu:0"))
dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.contrib.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can now fix this problem by using [prefetch_to_device](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/prefetch_to_device). Instead of the line:

```
dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
```

do

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device('/gpu:0', buffer_size=2))
```